# Split rows by months

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a big data set (100+ mil. rows) that i need to split to rows based on the number of months between the start_date and end_date for accounting purposes.

So for example this record should split into 3612 rows because theres 3612 months between start_date and end_date:

[image]

The result I am after should look like this:

[image]

I know I can achieve this using recursive CTE, but it takes FOREVER for dataset this big. Any more effective ways to do this?

Comment: Join with between date to a date dimension

Comment: Use a numbers table.

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this query I'm using `master.dbo.spt_values` as tally table. But it will not suit you since it has numbers only till 2048. So you must create your own number table and change `master.dbo.spt_values` with it in the query.

```
declare @t table (
    id int
    , start_date date
    , end_date date
    , months int
)

insert into @t
values (1, '19990101', '21000101', 1212)

select
    t.id, month_num = v.number + 1
    , total_days = sum(datediff(dd, dateadd(mm, v.number, t.start_date), dateadd(mm, v.number + 1, t.start_date))) over (partition by t.id)
    , t.start_date, t.end_date
from
    @t t
    join master.dbo.spt_values v on t.months > v.number
where
    v.type = 'P'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @numbers TABLE (ID int NOT NULL primary key);  
INSERT INTO  @numbers (ID)
VALUES
   (1)
  ,(2)
  ,(3)
  ,(4)
  ,(5)
  ,(6)
  ,(7)
  ,(8);

declare @range TABLE (cnt int);  
INSERT INTO  @range (cnt)
VALUES (1), (4), (6);

select r.cnt, n.ID
from @range r
join @numbers n 
  on n.ID < = r.cnt 
order by r.cnt, n.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do the exact same thing less than 1 week ago!

```
-----DLL

CREATE TABLE Reporting_Table (
    Credit_Line_NO    Varchar(10),
    noMonths         INT,
    EFFECTIVEDATE    Date,
    EXPIRY_DATE      Date,
    Amount           Money,
    mxDays           INT,
    mxFactor         decimal(5,4),
    Calc             Money)

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc)
 Values('9938810','3','3/31/2018','6/12/2020','11718.75','90','1','11718.75') 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc)
 Values('2235461','1','6/30/2018','6/6/2019','12345','30','1','12345') 

INSERT INTO Reporting_Table (Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc)
 Values('3365434','12','6/30/2018','6/30/2019','298523.36085','365','1.01388888888889','302669.518639583') 

---- VIEW DATA SET . . .
 Select *, (DATEDIFF(MONTH,EFFECTIVEDATE,EXPIRY_DATE)/noMonths)+1 as FREQ
 From Reporting_Table
```

-- Now that you have a working data set to fiddle around with, simply expand all relevant tows.

```
;with cte as
(
  select Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc,
         (DATEDIFF(MONTH,EFFECTIVEDATE,EXPIRY_DATE)/noMonths)+1 as FREQ,
         1 as Rec_Iteration
  from Reporting_Table
  where noMonths > 1
  union all  
  select Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc,
         (DATEDIFF(MONTH,EFFECTIVEDATE,EXPIRY_DATE)/noMonths)+1 as FREQ,
         Rec_Iteration + 1
  from cte 
  where Rec_Iteration < FREQ
)
select Credit_Line_NO, noMonths, EFFECTIVEDATE, EXPIRY_DATE, Amount, mxDays, mxFactor, Calc,
    (DATEDIFF(MONTH,EFFECTIVEDATE,EXPIRY_DATE)/noMonths)+1 as FREQ
from cte
order by Credit_Line_NO,
         Rec_Iteration
```